# jQuery: remove 1 item from array after the selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I create an array based on some button clicks.

Every time a button is clicked I get its `data-video` value and add that to an array.

I then immediately, add an extra video (`intro.mp4`) after each video that I add to my array.

This works fine.

Now, if I click on the same button(s) that I clicked on once, that item will be removed from the array.

This works fine too.

But I need to remove the `intro.mp4` that I added for that particular video as well. But when I try my code, it will remove all the intro.mp4 items from my array. I just need to delete 1 after the selected item.

Here is my code to help you understand better:

```js
var videoSource = [];

$(document).on('click', '.pSelection', function(e) {

  var vidToAdd = $(this).attr("data-video");

  ///check if its added/////
  if ($(this).hasClass("added")) {

    $(this).removeClass("added");

    e.stopPropagation();

    videoSource = videoSource.filter(x => x != vidToAdd);
    videoSource = videoSource.filter(x => x != 'intro.mp4');

    console.log(videoSource);

  } else {

    $(this).addClass('added');

    videoSource.push(vidToAdd);
    videoSource.push('intro.mp4');

    var videoCount = videoSource.length;

    console.log(videoSource);

    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.buildExDrop').hide();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid1.mp4">
Video 1
</button>

<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid2.mp4">
Video 2
</button>


<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid3.mp4">
Video 3
</button>


<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid4.mp4">
Video 4
</button>


<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid5.mp4">
Video 5
</button>
```

My problem is this part of my code as I understand:

```
videoSource = videoSource.filter(x => x != 'intro.mp4');
```

This is telling the code to remove all the instances of `intro.mp4` from the array.

But I don't know how to target only 1 after the selected item to remove it.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

To test the code above, click on a few buttons and keep looking at the `console.log();`...

once you have added a few items to array, click on one of the buttons that you've already added and see what happens.

Comment: can you store the information as objects? or are you restricted to pushing them this way?

Comment: @schylake, unfortunately I am forced to do it this way.

Comment: why do you need to push same intro for each video into array each time

Comment: @charlietfl, its just a requirement for the project.

Comment: Ok.. what i was really looking for is what is the use case?

Comment: you can do something where you remove the intro.mp4 located after the video found in the array?

Comment: @charlietfl, right... well, to keep it short, I play the videos from the array one after the other. however, everytime 1 video has ended, I need the intro.mp4 video to play in-between each video.

Comment: @schylake, that is sort of what I am looking for. basically, just remove the intro.mp4 immediately after the video found. not all of the intro.mp4

Comment: Do you *always* add intro.mp4 after the video you're adding?  And can you *only* remove videos (not intro.mp4)?  If so, when you remove your video, just remove the next one.  Instead of using `filter`, use `indexOf`.

Comment: Sure seems like it would be very simple to just play the intro in between the others without needing to push it into array each time. Use a simple flag for the conditional switching

Comment: @charlietfl, you are actually right. I might try to see if its best to just play the intro video in between other videos without adding it to the array. the only problem i would have is the fact that the array has a structure which I need to follow. i.e. the intro wont play after the first video in the array. that's why i tried to push it in the array so I know exactly where it needs to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the 2 entries by starting at the index of the known one

```js
var videoSource = [];

$(document).on('click', '.pSelection', function(e) {

  var vidToAdd = $(this).attr("data-video");

  ///check if its added/////
  if ($(this).hasClass("added")) {

    $(this).removeClass("added");
    e.stopPropagation();


    // make sure value is in array
    let sourceIndex = videoSource.indexOf(vidToAdd);
    if (sourceIndex > -1) {
      // then remove 2 elements
      videoSource.splice(sourceIndex, 2)
    }


    console.log(videoSource);

  } else {

    $(this).addClass('added');

    videoSource.push(vidToAdd);
    videoSource.push('intro.mp4');

    var videoCount = videoSource.length;

    console.log(videoSource);

    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.buildExDrop').hide();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid1.mp4">
Video 1
</button>

<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid2.mp4">
Video 2
</button>


<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid3.mp4">
Video 3
</button>


<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid4.mp4">
Video 4
</button>


<button class="pSelection" data-video="vid5.mp4">
Video 5
</button>
```

Comment: you beat me to it was just about to post this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop the `videoSource` array and find the index of videoLink you need to remove and store it in some variable.

```
var foundIndex = videoSource.indexOf("NAME OR LINK OF THE VIDEO");
```

then remove that item and to remove intro.mp4 next to that link. you can remove it by using `foundIndex + 1`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work: `var foundIndex = videoSource.indexOf(vidToAdd);  videoSource = videoSource.filter(x => x != foundIndex + 1);`

Comment: try this  `videoSource = videoSource.filter(x => x != videoSource[foundIndex + 1]);`